# Get the item from a collection that contains another collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Say I have a collection of `Layer`objects and each `Layer` may or may not contain a `Polygon` collection. There's only one `Layer` that contains the `Polygon` collection from the `Layer` collection. How do I obtain this Layer from the collection using LINQ?

Something like

```
foreach (var layer in Layers)
{
    var item = layer.FirstOrDefault( x =>x.Content is Polygon)
    if (item != null) return layer
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the first layer having a Polygon content like this: (using  `Enumerable.Any`):

```
return Layers.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Any(x => x.Content is Polygon));
```